# input mask to regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

I have an input mask which is 'DDDWD'.

I have to validate a string against this input mask. However to do that I have to make each character within that mask mean something to validate against!

i.e:

```
D = 0-9
W - a-z
```

I was going to store that information in a map and when I retrieve the input mask loop over the mask and then change all the `D`s to `0-9` by searching the map for a `D` and changing it to its corresponding value and so on. Following that I can the use those values with a regular expression

Does anyone have a better idea on changing the input mask to a meaning?

i.e `DDDWD` to `[0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z][0-9]` and using those within a regular expression?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but why not a structure associating one letter with a character validating function?

Comment: @fge reason being is because sometimes there my be part of a string which consists of DDD - [0-9][0-9][0-9] and some which consists D - [0-9] so it will not be the same all the time

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add either word boundries `\b` or string start/end tags `^$`.

Unsure if you want the case insensitive flag `flags=re.I`

```py
mappings = { "D": "0-9", "W": "a-z" }
def test_input_mask(mask: str, input: str) -> bool:
  #regex = r'\b' + "".join([ '['+mappings[char]+']' for char in mask ]) + r'\b' 
  regex  =   '^' + "".join([ '['+mappings[char]+']' for char in mask ]) +  '$' 
  match  = re.match(regex, input, flags=re.I)
  return bool(match)

test_input_mask("DDDWD", "123a4")     # True
test_input_mask("DDDWD", "123a4567")  # False
```